# Why am I getting Rep for Answering a Community Wiki Question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, community-wiki

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941770/concrete-symptoms-of-over-engineering) turned community wiki [at 2009-12-21 20:39:24Z](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1941770/list).

At that time my answer had about 10 upvotes, yet I've received 170 reputation for it so far. Answers to community wiki questions aren't supposed to award reputation, are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question became CW, but your answer hasn't. It's CW *posts* which don't earn rep. If for whatever reason your answer becomes CW, then *at that point* you won't receive any more rep from it.

Comment: Thanks! All along, I've thought that CW questions 'tainted' their answers!

Comment: Well *new* answers to a CW question are always CW by default... maybe that's what confused you?

Comment: @Jeff Sternal: a moderator can switch the question and all existing answers to CW.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal: Additionally, many find it to be good practice to set your own post CW (you can do so by editing) if it's appropriate. I had a similar situation with a post to a silly polling question where I realized too late that it wasn't CW. Even after the question switched, I had to manually switch my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've wiki'd the lot; it didn't seem fair for only *some* of the (early) answers to be rep-gaining. You'll keep any rep you gained so far (even after a recalc), but any *additional* votes are for glory and badges only.